# Best solution for selecting the columns that contain at least one True value in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [True, False, True], 'b': [False, False, False], 
   ...: 'c': [False, False, False], 'd': [False, True, False], 
   ...: 'e': [False, False, False]})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


In [5]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: 
       a      b      c      d      e
0   True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True  False
2   True  False  False  False  False

In [6]: df[df.any()[df.any()].index]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 
       a      d
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

The code under [6] does what I want. My question, however, is: is there a better solution? That is, more concise and/or more elegant.

Comment: How about 

    `df.loc[:, df.any()]` ?

Comment: @cs95, well, you could consider making your comment an answer, since it obviously is better than my solution! I guess I will read again the ".loc" documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One direct method is using `df.loc` with the mask generated by `df.any()` as input:

```
df.loc[:, df.any()]

       a      d
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

---

Another option is to index `df.columns`,

```
df[df.columns[df.any()]]
```

Or, `df.keys()`:

```
df[df.keys()[df.any()]]
```

```
       a      d
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.loc, Allowed inputs are: [...] A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True]. That's the case here, right? What's the exact mechanism of transformation of the Series into an array?

Comment: @nilo `loc` accepts boolean masks or string labels. The exact nature of the argument is inferred somewhere deep in the entrails of the internals.

Comment: I realize now that this is "regular" masking, as "already" available in NumPy. I'm just starting to learn these libraries...